# iOS keyboard flickers when switching view controllers

Tags: ios

I have a registration form and I want to have the keyboard always on top.
The way I'm doing it now, is that when the user moves between view controllers, in viewDidLoad, the first UITextField becomes the first responder.
The problem is that the keyboard flickers (disappears and then appears again) when the user moves between view controllers.

Also, related to this: I have a form with a few uitextfields. When the user presses next it goes to the next uitextfield using becomefirstresponder. When the user is in the last textfield, the keyboard button becomes "Done". Then, when the user presses it, if there's an error with the last field, it should get the focus (calls becomeFirstResponder) but that doesn't happen (nothing get's the focus and the keyboard goes down). All the other fields get the focus fine, just this last field doesn't. I've tried about everything: switching to other textfields and back. The problem is that done automatically removes the keyboard.

Comment: The second question really should be a seperate question. This way people can answer either question and you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have made two separate questions for this.

First, your flickering:

I'm guessing you're using a UINavigationController. You can add an invisible UITextField somewhere in the UINavigationController, which you give focus before you switch to a new ViewController. Then, when the new ViewController has appeared (`viewDidAppear`), set the focus to the first textField as you want.

However, the entire approach is kind of hackey and I don't recommend you use it. Instead, try using several views in a scrollView, of which you change the offset when you move to the new view. This will also solve the flickering.

Second, losing firstResponder status on Done:

The done button is specifically there to indicate exactly that which it says; Done. Pressing this assumes the user is finished and that no text is left to type, thus dismissing the keyboard.

If you really want to keep the Done button, then try the following;

1. Allow the user to dismiss the keyboard.
2. Upon dismissal, check for the error in the last field.
3. If there is an error, instead of calling `[lastField becomeFirstResponder]`, try `[self performSelector:@selector(thisSelectorWillCallFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0]`.
4. In the method `thisSelectorWillCallFirstResponder` call `[lastField becomeFirstResponder]`.

This will give time for the keyboard to disappear, before making it pop up again, so it doesn't interfere with the `becomeFirstResponder` call.

Another method would be to not use a Done button, but instead use the return key. You can intercept return anytime with the delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn:`. There you can handle any error checking, without causing the textField to lose its focus.

Comment: Thanks! and sorry about the two questions. Just one problem: the invisible textfield solution doesn't work perfect (there's still some flickering). Am I doing something wrong or is there just a problem with it? The scroll view solution is not possible for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: No worries. We all joined this site once. Can't help you further with the flickering though. The problem is that you're using multiple viewControllers for what is essentially one task (filling in the entire form). Apple's idea is that a viewController exists for a single task, which is discontinued when the viewController is no longer the focus. Thus, it also disables anything that's currently ongoing, such as the keyboard. No way around that, I'm afraid. Either it's all one view, or you allow the keyboard to disappear and appear nicely when a new viewController comes up.